# How i can update my todo status using checkbox in mean stack if check box is checked it place true in mongodb database otherwise false

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

**app.component.ts**

Debugger given the error that this.task is undefined

```
updateTodo(task: any){
    this.todoService.updateData(task._id, this.task).subscribe(res => {
    this.data= res;
    console.log(res);
    console.log(this.task);
    });
}
```

**app.service.ts**

This is service file where the backend api are call in my angular app

```
updateData(id: any , data: any){
    return this.httpClient.put('http://localhost:3000/todos/'+id, data);
}
```

**app.component.html**

This is the frontend of my app where the todos show and others user interface

```html
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let todo of tasks ; let i = index">
        <td>{{todo.todos}}</td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox" (change)="updateTodo(todo)"[checked]="todo.isDone</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="del-btn" 
            (click)="deleteData(todo._id)">Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**app.model.ts**

This is model file

```
export class Todo {
    _id:any;
    todos:any;
    isDone:any;
}
```

**backend api**

This is the backedn function which i created to update my todo

```
router.put('/:id' , async (req,res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    if(ObjectId.isValid(id)){
        const todo = (req.body);
        const todoUpdate = await Todo.findByIdAndUpdate(id ,{$set:emp}, {new:true});
        res.status(200).json({code:200, message:'Todo Updated Successfully'});
    }
    else{
        res.status(400).send('Todo Not Found By Given Id' + id);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your `updateTodo` function takes `task` as a parameter, but you send `this.task` as a param to `updateData()` function. Is it a typo?

Comment: yes  this is typescript but i am begginer i not know how can solve this

Comment: Yes means that it's a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this question to add [(ngModel)]="todo.isDone" in my checkbox input filed

```
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let todo of tasks ; let i = index">
    <td>{{todo.todos}}</td>
    <td> <input type="checkbox" (change)="updateTodo(todo)" [(ngModel)]="todo.isDone</td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="del-btn" 
        (click)="deleteData(todo._id)">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And In my app.component.ts

```
updateTodo(task: any) {
  this.todoService.updateData(task._id, task).subscribe(res => {
  this.data = res;
  console.log(res);
  console.log(task);
```

});
}

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if we understood each other, but you are passing the `task` as a parameter but then on two occasions you are trying to use the value of `this.task`. They are not the same thing and if `this.task` is not initialized then of course it will show that it's `undefined`.

```
updateTodo(task: any) {
  console.log('task:', task); // Is the task correct?
  this.todoService.updateData(task._id, task).subscribe(res => {
    this.data = res;
    console.log(res);
    console.log(task); //not this.task
  });
}
```

EDIT:
If the DB is not updated you might be sending incorrect data there. If there are no errors on Angular side you have to check the Back-End side.

Comment: i also try this code but still not working .

Comment: everything is working fine but data in not updated in the database

Comment: Updated the answer a little bit